# Linear algebra overline notation question

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

In terms of linear algebra, what does the following notation mean: $\overline{XX*}$ ?

I saw this notation in the following:
"The $M\times M$ covariance matrix of the $X$ vector is: $\overline{XX*}$"

I understand $X*$ is the conjugate transpose of $X$, but I don't understand why a bar is over $\overline{XX*}$.

Is this notation just a notation for a covariance matrix? I had thought a covariance matrix of vector $X$ would be notated as $R_{XX}$.

Comment: Where did you see this notation? What is the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a covariance matrix, then the overline means expectation. If the coordinates of $X$ are centered random variables, then the covariance matrix is exactly $\mathbb{E}(XX^T)$, yours is just different notation for this. Is $X$ centered in your case?

Comment: I'm not sure about X being centered here. I know that X is an M-element complex vector: [X1, X2, ..., XM]

Comment: Is this in a paper? Can you give a link?

Comment: Notation is at Equation (2) at : https://msol.people.uic.edu/ECE531/papers/Multiple%20Emitter%20Location%20and%20Signal%20Parameter%20Estimation.pdf

Comment: I don't see the assumption of mean zero explicitly, but I see no other interpretation for the overline other than the expectation, it makes sense in the context.